# Angular returns response without my custom headers

Tags: angular, typescript, http, nginx, request

I'm trying to get headers from request in Angular, but it returns only this:
[image: headers]

The weird thing about it is, that if I copy the request as cURL and use it, the headers are working.

Request:

```
  login(email, password): Observable<string> {
    const url = Utils.baseBackendUrl + '/login';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    const httpOptions = {
      observe: 'response',
      // method: 'POST',
      // headers: headers,
    };
    this.http.post<any>(url, {
      user_email: email,
      user_password: password,
      locale: 'cs_CZ'
    }, {headers: headers, observe: 'response'})
      .subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp.headers);
    });
    return of('ahoj');
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you actually try to [`.get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#get) one of the headers? Note that they're lazily evaluated. Also are they permitted by [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't use get, only post is allowed. Access-Control-Expose-Headers is needed? I thought that if it works with CURL, it should work in browser too.

Comment: `headers.get`, not `http.get`. And no, CURL handles things differently than your browser, as security is less of an issue.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, I tried getting the header, but returns null. Where should be Access-Control-Expose-Headers set? In nginx? Manually in backend response?

Comment: Up to you, somewhere on the server side; it depends on your exact setup what is most appropriate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok thanks :) I just want to point out one more thing: When I open google chrome Network tab I can see 2 requests there - login, login. One of them CONTAINS my headers. https://imgur.com/a/oRs41

Comment: Wait you're adding a header to a 200 OK response to say whether it was actually successful? That's... not great.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well :/ I know, but it already is that way. No chance to change it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a working solution for my problem!

```
  login(email, password): Observable<string> {
    const url = Utils.baseBackendUrl + '/login';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    this.http.post<any>(url, JSON.stringify({'user_email': email, 'user_password': password, 'locale': 'cs_CZ'}),
      {headers: headers, observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' as 'json'})
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp.headers.get('successful'));
        console.log(resp.headers.get('message'));
    });
    return of('ahoj');
  }
```